# Don't overlap nodes in GOJS for ForceDirectedLayout

Tags: layout, gojs

I am using go js to draw diagrams by drag and drop , i want to draw a network diagram for that I used **GO js** and used **ForceDirectedLayout** , but the problem is my nodes are overlapping on each other but i dont want that. is there any way to dont allow to overlap nodes on each other in  **ForceDirectedLayout**.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible for **ForceDirectedLayout** to guarantee that no nodes overlap each other, but in order to decrease the chance of overlaps, you could increase its values of **maxIterations** and **defaultElectricalCharge**.

https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/ForceDirectedLayout.html#maxIterations

https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/ForceDirectedLayout.html#defaultElectricalCharge

If your nodes are unusually large, you might also want to increase the value of **defaultSpringLength**.

https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/ForceDirectedLayout.html#defaultSpringLength

Comment: is there any other layout which will display network diagram like structure where nodes will not overlap on each other. and looks like network.?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are looking for.  Have you seen https://gojs.net/latest/samples or read https://gojs.net/latest/intro/layouts.html ?

Comment: Thanks  @walter i gone through https://gojs.net/latest/samples and i got https://gojs.net/latest/samples/pageFlow.html which is what i want , its worked for me. Thanks.